# Change uploading path from one server to other server in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to change path of uploading files from one server path to other server path,
for example if my site is hosted on my one server , and if server space is full admin will be able to change uploading path to my other server in codeigniter.

Comment: Not so clear about what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

There is that upload_tmp_dir setting that will allow you to change the upload path. 
After that you will have to mount on the php server the storage one.

Check [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS)

and [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `move_uploaded_file()` function.
in the `$_FILES` variable,you can change the `tmp_name`.first create variable which is the new path.
in windows:

```
$destination = 'C:/your_path_here/';
```

in mac:

```
$destination = '/Users/username/your_path_here/';
```

be aware,if you're using back-slash instead of the normal-slash in windows,you must use Two back-slashes at the end.like this:

```
$destination = 'C:\your_path_here\\';
```

in the html form,if the input file name is `image`,then the PHP file should look like this:

```html
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {  //upload is the name of the submit button
    //move uploaded file 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$destination . $FILES['image']['name']);
}
```